# How to access PUTed data in PHP

Tags: php, json

HeIIo, I'm sending a json array via `PUT` method. The problem is, that on PHP side, I don't know how to handle it and drop it into pieces, such as
    `$data['id']` and `$data['name']`
What I tried was

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($input);
echo print_r($data);
$id = $data['id'];
echo $id;
```

It echoes a pretty normal looking array, but the 4th line gives me the

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>/home/alexa449/public_html/biom/websitec/php/api.php</b> on line
```

Can someone help to handle this. Thank you.

Comment: As the error message says, `$data` is not array, so you have to do `$data->id`. As so often, reading the documentation helps: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php.

Comment: Also simply searching for the error message here on SO returns a lot of answers: [`[json] Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+use+object+of+type+stdClass+as+array+)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$content = stream_get_contents(fopen('php://input', 'r'));
parse_str($content, $parameters);
var_dump($parameters);
```